3 way switch - Motion Switch activates, light doesn't illuminate - Leviton DOS05
We have an older house, probably wiring from the 50's.  I replaced one switch that works as a three way with a Leviton DOS05 motion detector.  The sensors light up in the switch, the motion detection works (I can hear it switching on and off), flipping the other light switch causes the motion switch to turn on and off, but I cannot get the actual light fixture to illuminate.  What am I missing?

As always, pictures of before and after your wired it would help. Most likely you didn't wire it properly according to the instructions.

This switch is compatible with 3-way wiring. But it has to be installed the correct way. The instructions have all the details.
There are a lot of ways to install 3-way switches. In the end, they (mostly) come down to:

Panel -> Switch 1 -> Switch 2 -> Light

but the wire colors can be pretty much anything.
In addition, some 3-way switches will have neutral available and some won't, which also affects wiring as described in the instructions.
From the instructions: Sensor must be installed in the location where the load wire is. That means Switch 2. But you can't tell which switch is which except by figuring out what wires are where, particularly Line/Hot vs. Load/Switched Hot.
So the first step is to identify the line/hot wire in one of the boxes. You can do that by turning off the breaker, disconnecting all wires except grounds and spreading them out carefully and safely, and then turning on the breaker and testing which wire is hot with a non-contact voltage tester. Once you know which wire is hot, you know which cable (or, less commonly, conduit) is coming from the panel with hot/neutral. Depending on whether you have two cables in each box or three cables in this box and one on the other box, it should not be too hard to figure out which cable is going between the switches and which cable is going to the light fixture.
There are a lot of possibilities, so rather than guess which one you have, I'll wait for pictures showing (ideally) "before" wiring and the current (such as it is) wiring in each box. But if you can identify the hot wire first, that will help.
You also need to figure out neutral. The instructions vary depending on whether you have neutral in the switch box (in this case, the Switch 2 box) or not. But remember, neutral is always white, white is not always neutral. The cable between the switches can have many different configurations, including:

Hot + two travelers
Switched hot + two travelers
Neutral + two travelers

even though, assuming standard US cables, it will nearly always be black/red/white.
